# Code First Enable Migration

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, visual-studio

I receive this error:

Additional information: The model backing the 'ApplicationDbContext' context has changed since the database was created. Consider using Code First Migrations to update the database (http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=238269).

Go to that link, and click on the tutorial section for Enabling Migrations which has a link on how to do this. Where do you think this link goes? BACK TO THE SAME PAGE. The documentation is consistently horrendous.

It seems like it should be a checkbox somewhere, or a line of code that I need to add, but I don’t know where to find it.

Healy in Tampa

Comment: I looked at question first, but none of those answers are this one below.  Also a different issue. In the linked question, user was attempting to share a connection string (i.e. a database) with two separate entities.

Answer (score 3):

The [documentation on the Microsoft site](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj591621.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396#enabling) isn't very clear. I first came across an issue where I needed to enable migrations when working on an ASP.NET application which relied on the Entity Framework.

The error thrown was the same:

> *Additional information: The model backing the 'ApplicationDbContext' context has changed since the database was created. Consider using
>   Code First Migrations to update the database
>   (http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=238269).*

This was a result of me adding a new property to one of my models. When I looked at the controller, it did not update to reflect the new property. If I navigated to *http://localhost:59108/Controller* I received that message within the Visual Studio 2015 debugger.

**To enable migrations, which will update your database when you add a new property to my model and controller, do the following:**

Navigate to the **Package Manager Console** in Visual Studio. (View -> Other Windows -> Package Manager Console). Enter this text:

1. Enable-Migrations

When it asks for a **name** enter the name of a new table you'd like to use -- it can be anything.

(**UPDATE**, from @DrewJordan: it asks for a name when you do add-migration, and it's nothing (inherently) to do with a new table; it's a new migration, and it helps to give descriptive names to your migrations. Like 'AddFooToBar' for adding a Foo property to table Bar.)

2. Add-Migration
3. Update-Database
4. Rebuild your project
5. Deploy

Comment: good answer... except for "When it asks for a name enter the name of a new table you'd like to use -- it can be anything.". it asks for a name when you do *add-migration*, and it's nothing (inherently) to do with a new table; it's a new migration, and it helps to give descriptive names to your migrations. Like 'AddFooToBar' for adding a Foo property to table Bar.

Comment: Very good point! Let me update that.

I was initially confused by 'name' as well, because I actually had a property called 'name', so I first thought it was asking me to fill values based on that.